# How to use function to call it inside the button?

Tags: flutter, function, widget, flutter-future

Currently, I use Navigation to bring up `Dialog`. But of course, the page will be changed, and the screen will only display the `Dialog`. Like I've shown below.

I want to fix it, so that when the `Dialog` appears, the page behind it wouldn't disappear, like in the picture below.

This is my code, with `NavigationHelper`, the screen will move to another screen to display `Dialog`, which I want to change.

```dart
PopupMenuItem(
  onTap: () {
    GetIt.I<NavigationHelper>().go('/alert_delete_item');
  },
  value: 'Delete',
),
```

And this is a template to handle the `Dialog`, but I do not know how to use it.

```dart
Future<T?> showCustomDialog<T>(BuildContext context) {
  return showDialog<T>(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) => Dialog(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
      ),
      child: this,
    ),
  );
}
```

Any tutorial on how to use the function?

Comment: Kindly add reproducible code here about what you've done so far. Otherwise, how will people help you?

Comment: Wait a second, I add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should try this

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

  void main() {runApp(new MyApp());}

  class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter',
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Dummy Screen')), 
          body: HomePage()
        )
      );
    }
  }

  class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {showAlertDialoge(context);},
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 20,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text("Heading ${index}" , style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,),
              subtitle: Text("This is subtitle ${index}" ,),
            );
          },
        ),
      );
    }

    void showAlertDialoge(BuildContext context) {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
          content: Text("Dialog Box Occur in front of screen", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),),
        )
      );
    }
  }
```

**OutPut:**

[image]